# Kivy-Python error after releasing VideoCapture(0) and setting kivy camera.play = True

Tags: python, opencv, kivy

```
    import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import datetime
import math
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist


import os
import image_processing as imp

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera

class NoteCutterGrid(GridLayout):
    __mode = 1
    __auto_find = True
    __show_settings = False
    __sharpness = 30
    __grayscale = 0

    def take_photo(self):
        self.ids['camera'].play = False
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cap.release()
        if ret:
            res = imp.image_processing(frame, (self.__mode - 1), self.__grayscale, self.__sharpness)
            for image in res:
                imp.save_image(image)
        self.ids['camera'].play = True
```

If I don't write `self.ids['camera'].play = True`, it do function `image_processing`, but camera in the app still be freezed. I want to unfreeze it after saving images taken from VideoCapture, but it returns an ERROR many times:

> [ERROR  ] [OpenCV      ] Couldn't get image from Camera
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Tioma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py", line 139, in _update
>
> self._buffer = frame.imageData
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'imageData'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Tioma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py", line 143, in _update
>
> self._buffer = frame.tostring()
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tostring'

Comment: I don't see a single question mark, so what's your question? Also, reformat your code and text. Make use of code blocks (4 indents) to markt your errors with monofont.

Comment: please, provide a [mcve] :)